# Laravel: Problema com foreach

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, foreach

```
public function extract(){
    $occupation = Occupation::join('invoices', 'occupations.id', '=', 'invoices.occupation_id')
        ->leftJoin('payments', 'invoices.id', '=', 'payments.invoice_id')
        ->select('occupations.*',
            'invoices.occupation_id',
            'invoices.id as invoiceId',
            'invoices.date_invoice',
            'invoices.date_pay',
            'invoices.ufir as invoiceUfir',
            'payments.date_payment',
            'payments.value')
        ->find(1);
    return view('occupation/extract', ['occupation' => $occupation]);
}
```

Esse é meu Controller.

```
@foreach($occupation as $o)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $o->invoiceId }}</td>
    <td>{{ date('m/Y', strtotime($o->date_invoice)) }}</td>
    <td>{{ date('d/m/Y', strtotime($o->date_pay)) }}</td>
    <td>{{ number_format(($o->invoiceUfir), 2, ',', '.') }}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>{{ date('d/m/Y', strtotime($o->date_payment)) }}</td>
    <td>{{ number_format($o->value, 2, ',', '.') }}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Esse é meu Blade.

Quando coloco sem o @foreach funciona perfeitamente, agora quando eu o coloco para trazer as demais informações da o erro:

"Trying to get property '***' of non-object (View: C:\Users\grosa\Desktop\Laravel\siscom\resources\views\occupation\extract.blade.php)".

Aguardo o apoio de vocês. Agradeço desde já a colaboração.

Comment: Da uma sacada como o objeto ta saindo do teu controller da um "dd" nele depois que a query rodar

Comment: Se está selecionando apenas um registro, `find(1)`, por quê quer fazer o `foreach`?

Comment: Verdade, esqueci que estava com o find(1), mas quando coloco o get() ele roda do dd() tranquilo, porém no Blade ele da o seguinte erro "Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance."

Comment: E qual foi a saída do `dd`? Posta na pergunta...

Answer (score -1):

Então, consegui resolver o problema.

```
public function extract(Occupation $occupation){
    $occupations = Occupation::join('invoices', 'occupations.id', '=', 'invoices.occupation_id')
        ->leftJoin('payments', 'invoices.id', '=', 'payments.invoice_id')
        ->select('occupations.id',
            'invoices.occupation_id',
            'invoices.id as invoiceId',
            'invoices.date_invoice',
            'invoices.date_pay',
            'invoices.ufir as invoiceUfir',
            'payments.date_payment',
            'payments.value')
        ->get();
    return view('occupation/extract', compact('occupation', 'occupations'));
}
```

O Controller.

```
@foreach($occupations as $o)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $o->invoiceId }}</td>
    <td>{{ date('m/Y', strtotime($o->date_invoice)) }}</td>
    <td>{{ date('d/m/Y', strtotime($o->date_pay)) }}</td>
    <td>{{ number_format(($o->invoiceUfir), 2, ',', '.') }}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>{{ date('d/m/Y', strtotime($o->date_payment)) }}</td>
    <td>{{ number_format($o->value, 2, ',', '.') }}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

O Blade.

Especifiquei no Controller apenas o que necessitava no @foreach.